# firebase not populating realtime in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

I'm creating an application with Swift and Firebase and everything is fine but I have only one issue located in nested table inside Firebase Database

App scenario is like Instagram, I'm commenting on someone post that it's reflecting instantly in tableview but when I'm replying to that comment the replied comment doesn't appear in tableview, I need to go back and return again to comment screen, it's showing me comments but if there is more than one comment, It's always showing the last added comment

here is my Firebase Table Structure as Screen Shot

[In this table i have main comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WURHS.png)

as you can see in screen shot first i am fetching `id` which is under `comments` table

[This is the Reply Comment Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kfgn.png)

as you can able to seen in second table i have table named `reply` but its not reflecting in side my app here is my code to displays comment

```
func getCommentId(){
        let getPostComment = Database.database().reference().child("user-post-iOS").child(post_id).child("comments")
        getPostComment.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            guard let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else { return }
            self.commentData.removeAll()
            for data in snapshot{
                let key = data.key
                self.getCommentData(key: key)
            }
        } withCancel: { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    func getCommentData(key: String){
        let commentsDataRef = Database.database().reference().child("user-comments-iOS").child(key)
        commentsDataRef.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
                let comment = dict["comment"] as? String
                let comment_by = dict["comment_by"] as? String
                let created_at = dict["created_at"] as? Double
                let id = dict["id"] as? String
                let parent_id = dict["parent_id"] as? String
                let post_id = dict["post_id"] as? String
                //let reply = dict["reply"] as? String
                let updated_at = dict["updated_at"] as? String
                if let reply = dict["reply"] as? [String:AnyObject]{
                    self.commentData.append(CommentModel(comment: comment, comment_by: comment_by, created_at: created_at, id: id, parent_id: parent_id, post_id: post_id, updated_at: updated_at, reply: reply, isReply: true))
                }else{
                    let emptyDictionary = [String: AnyObject]()
                    self.commentData.append(CommentModel(comment: comment, comment_by: comment_by, created_at: created_at, id: id, parent_id: parent_id, post_id: post_id, updated_at: updated_at, reply: emptyDictionary, isReply: false))
                }
                //print(self.commentData)
            }
            self.tblListView.reloadData()
            commentsDataRef.removeAllObservers()
        } withCancel: { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }


extension PostCommentsViewController: UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        //let title = "Title"
        //let subtitle = "Sub title"
        
        // Dequeue with the reuse identifier
        let header = self.tblListView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! MainCommentTableViewCell
        header.btnReply.tag = section
        header.btnLike.tag = section
        header.btnUnLike.tag = section
        header.btnDeleteMain.tag = section
        header.lblComment.text = self.commentData[section].comment
        //header.subtitleLabel.text = subtitle
        
        header.fetchLikes(id: self.commentData[section].id)
        let parent_id = self.commentData[section].parent_id
        let nameReference = Database.database().reference().child("user-iOS").child(parent_id).child("username")
        nameReference.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.exists() {
                header.lblName.text = snapshot.value as? String
            }
        })
        let photoReference = Database.database().reference().child("user-iOS").child(parent_id).child("profile_pic")
        photoReference.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.exists() {
                let photo = snapshot.value as? String
                header.imgProPic.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: photo!), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "ic_ProPic"), options: [.scaleDownLargeImages , .continueInBackground], completed: { (_, _, _, _) in
                })
            }
        })
        header.imgProPic.layer.cornerRadius = header.imgProPic.frame.height / 2
        let timestamp = self.commentData[section].created_at
        let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp)
        let dateToCalculate = date.timeAgoSinceDate()
        header.lblDate.text = dateToCalculate
        return header
    }
    
    // Give a height to our table view cell
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }
    
    // We have only one section
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.commentData.count
    }
    
    // One cell is enough
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.commentData[section].reply.count
    }
    
    // Cell creation
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReplyCell") as! ReplyCommentTableViewCell
        let reply = self.commentData[indexPath.section].reply
        for rp in reply{
            cell.fetchReplyComment(key: rp.key)
        }
        cell.btnReply.tag = indexPath.section
        cell.btnLike.tag = indexPath.section
        cell.btnUnLike.tag = indexPath.section

        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell
    }
}
```

My main issue is that when any user replied to a comment then it's not showing and also when I go back and come again I discovered that it always shows the last comment not all the comments.

can any one help me out to solve this?

Comment: Do you happen to know that each sentence ends with the period in English?  What do you mean by "so scenario is like Instagram i am commenting on someone post that its reflecting instantly in tableview but when i am replying to that comment than replied comment not showing in tableview i need to go back and than again got to comment screen than its showing me comment but if comment is more than one that alway its showing last added comment"?

Comment: simply i want to say when i replied in any comment than its not showing in tableview realtime

Comment: yes i looked up sorry my mistake i will update it

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure.